# Create a SQL Credential for a Managed Service Account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, credentials

Is it possible to create a SQL Credential in SQL 2019 for a Managed Service Account?

When I try, it asks for a password, which I don't know. I want to run a Powershell command from SQL Agent using this credential as a proxy, but can't add the credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You can't create a credential without a password, and so can't use a MSA or gMSA.